# how do i add network in wificonfig after API level26

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi

i am facing a problem with wifi if the ap has same ssid and password i am getting BSSID as null or any from getconfiguredNetwork() method. so, i want to add network manually into wifi configuration but this add,remove and update will not work from api levl 26. is there any other alternative way to solve this solution. [Reference Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#saveConfiguration()).

```
   WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
    conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
    conf.BSSID = Bssid;
    conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + networkPasskey + "\"";
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for (WifiConfiguration i : list) {
        if (i.BSSID != null && i.BSSID.equals(Bssid)) {
            wifiManager.disconnect();
            wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
            wifiManager.reassociate();
            Log.d("changing network", "connecting the right network");
            break;
        }

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will require location permissions, starting with Android 8.1 and 9 Google changed how you can access WiFi info.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all#restricted_access_to_wi-fi_location_and_connection_information

You will need ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions as well as rely on the user having their location service enabled. This cannot be done any other way because of privacy issues relating to WiFi.

Comment: No because it's an API limitation. I recommend you ask for runtime permissions for user's location (ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION is enough) and explain to the user specifically why you need it, something like ("This app requires your coarse location because of limitations on WiFi information that is required to properly run this app. Your physical location will not be accessed or used, only your WiFi info."). Then have a null/permission check to make sure the user has given you the needed permissions, if they did not show them that explanation in a dialog. Then you will be able to access WiFi info.